# Should I return more suggestions then there are relevant documents in a precision-recall curve?

Tags: machine-learning, information-retrieval, precision-recall

I am trying to plot a precision-recall curve, but I have more document recommendations than relevant documents. Let´s say for one training example, there are just 3 relevant documents: A, C, E. But it could be all documents from A to Z. Then I vectorize this into:

original = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ... ]

And let´s say my prediction has the biggest values for A,C,E and small values for all other documents:

prediction = [0.9, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.7, ... ]

Then I calculate precision and recall for the top-k predictions, first only using the prediction with {0.9}, then with {0.9 , 0.8} and {0.9, 0.8, 0.7}. Until then my precision is 1. But after that, the precision can only drop because there are no more relevant documents. Is it right to go on calculating precision/recall with {0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.1,  ...}?

I think I found the flaw by asking the question, when I return the recommendations {0.9, 0.8, 0.7} not only the precision is 1, but also the recall. I should stop to return documents then, right?

**EDIT: The explanation is that more documents can be returned, but after returning all relevant docs the Recall stays 1, and the precision drops down in a straigt line.**

Comment: Finding the answer by asking the question is always the -way of the programmer- you rock!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it depends what are the relevant dimensions for your curve, i.e., what are the parameters which their effect you'd like to measure?

For instance, if the interesting parameter is k, the number of documents returned, then you can vary it from 1 to some n, and calculate P/R for each point (and indeed, you might get a very steep line after passing a certain value).

You can also use other sachems, e.g. of using  a threshold - returning all documents with scores larger than some s. In this case, you can vary s from 1 to, say, 0.1, and calculate P/R for each point.

Assuming you perform the test on several test instances, one would expect that the exact number of matching documents would be different; thus, for a given (reasonable) k, the average precision and recall would be smaller than 1, even if for one of the specific instances the number of relevant documents is less than k.